# NaN values in decoded audio data

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, pcm

I want to get pcm samples from audio file using `MediaCodec`. I successfully got them, but there are NaN values in decoded data.

What do those mean? How to eliminate them?

Here is my code:

```
public float[] getPCMSamples(String audioPath) throws IOException {
    MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    MediaCodec decoder = null;

    int byte_num = 0;
    extractor.setDataSource(audioPath);
    int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) {
        MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        if (mime.startsWith("audio/")) {
            extractor.selectTrack(i);
            decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
            decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);

            int rate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
            int channels = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);
            long duration = format.getLong(MediaFormat.KEY_DURATION);
            duration = (duration / 1000000) + 1;
            int bitspersample = 16;
            //compute how much byte required for whole song
            byte_num = (rate * channels * (int) duration * bitspersample) / 8;
        }
    }

    //Decode
    decoder.start();
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
    //info for passing to the dequeueOutputBuffer
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    //flag for the end of the stream
    boolean isEOS = false;
    //holding bytes obtained from each outputBuffer
    byte[] decodedBytes = new byte[byte_num];
    //index of decoded bytes so far
    int decodedIdx = 0;

    //Start decoding
    while (true) {
        //fill inputBuffer with audio encoded data
        if (!isEOS) {
            int inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex], 0);
                if (sampleSize < 0) {
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    isEOS = true;
                } else {
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }
        }

        int outputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
        if (outputBufIndex >= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "got frame, size " + info.size + "/" + info.presentationTimeUs);
            ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outputBufIndex];

            byte[] temp = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(temp);
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, decodedBytes, decodedIdx, temp.length);
            decodedIdx += temp.length;

            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false /* render */);
            if (info.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw output EOS.");
                break;
            }
        } else if (outputBufIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();

            Log.d(TAG, "output buffers have changed.");
        } else if (outputBufIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat oformat = decoder.getOutputFormat();

            Log.d(TAG, "output format has changed to " + oformat);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "dequeueOutputBuffer returned " + outputBufIndex);
        }
    }
    decoder.stop();
    decoder.release();

    FloatBuffer floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decodedBytes).asFloatBuffer();
    float[] decoded = new float[floatBuffer.remaining()];
    floatBuffer.get(decoded);

    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: NaN is Not A Number.  Its what you get when you try to do something impossible, like divide by 0.  To get them either your algorithm is wrong (need to prevent those impossible operations) or your data is bad.  Figure out which and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw, decoded audio on android is normally 16 bit integers, not floats. So instead of `FloatBuffer`, use `ShortBuffer`.

Comment: Then how to get shorts to floats?